# Error with Xorg + Intel driver

Tags: xorg, configuration, intel, tearing, visual-artifacts

I try to remove tearing video using custom Intel driver config

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "X.org Configured"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
EndSection

Section "Files"
    ModulePath   "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi"
    FontPath     "built-ins"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load  "glx"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Keyboard0"
    Driver      "kbd"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Mouse0"
    Driver      "mouse"
    Option      "Protocol" "auto"
    Option      "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
    Option      "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor0"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: <i>: integer, <f>: float, <bool>: "True"/"False",
        ### <string>: "String", <freq>: "<f> Hz/kHz/MHz",
        ### <percent>: "<f>%"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "Accel"                 # [<bool>]
        Option     "AccelMethod" "sna"          # <str>
        #Option     "Backlight"             # <str>
        #Option     "CustomEDID"            # <str>
        #Option     "DRI"                   # <str>
        #Option     "Present"               # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ColorKey"              # <i>
        #Option     "VideoKey"              # <i>
        #Option     "Tiling"                # [<bool>]
        #Option     "LinearFramebuffer"     # [<bool>]
        #Option     "HWRotation"            # [<bool>]
        #Option     "VSync"                 # [<bool>]
        #Option     "PageFlip"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "SwapbuffersWait"       # [<bool>]
        #Option     "TripleBuffer"          # [<bool>]
        #Option     "XvPreferOverlay"       # [<bool>]
        #Option     "HotPlug"               # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ReprobeOutputs"        # [<bool>]
        #Option     "XvMC"                  # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ZaphodHeads"           # <str>
        #Option     "VirtualHeads"          # <i>
        Option      "TearFree" "True"           # [<bool>]
        #Option     "PerCrtcPixmaps"        # [<bool>]
        #Option     "FallbackDebug"         # [<bool>]
        #Option     "DebugFlushBatches"     # [<bool>]
        #Option     "DebugFlushCaches"      # [<bool>]
        #Option     "DebugWait"             # [<bool>]
        #Option     "BufferCache"           # [<bool>]
    Identifier  "Card0"
    Driver      "intel"
    BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    Device     "Card0"
    Monitor    "Monitor0"
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     1
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     4
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     8
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     15
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     16
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

I started X session using startx

```
startx -- -config ./xorg.conf.new -logverbose 6
```

But I've got the visible artifacts (see img)

[I have some visible artifacts when I use custom Intel configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4Dmw.png)

Also I send my Xorg.0.log file [here](https://pastebin.com/FD6Zqh3k)

Without the additional Intel configuration Xorg works fine (with tearing) maybe because Xorg loads modesetting_drv.so, not intel_drv.so.

My processor is Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-10210U CPU, only integrated Intel videocard (without NVIDIA and AMD)

But I cannot understand how to solve this problem.

**EDIT 1** My notebook is Dell Vostro 3590
Integrated videocard is Intel UHD Graphics 620 (info from [here](https://www.notebookcheck.net/Intel-Core-i5-10210U-Laptop-Processor-Comet-Lake-U.430587.0.html))

Also I ran lspci for VGA controller

```
aleksey@aleksey-Vostro-3590:~$ sudo lspci -vnnnn | grep VGA -A 16
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9b41] (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:096a]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 138
    Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 4000 [size=64]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [40] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [ac] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [100] Process Address Space ID (PASID)
    Capabilities: [200] Address Translation Service (ATS)
    Capabilities: [300] Page Request Interface (PRI)
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
```

Comment: Provide detail on the video card rather than on your processor. Specifying your brand and type of computer also may help users find the specs.

Comment: okey, i have filled additional information about notebook and videocard

Comment: Any more info on this? I have the exact same tearing problem on the exact same hardware, using Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem and I started testing different things today. In the end, what solved the issue for me (at least on YouTube videos, which is where the error is most noticeable -- for instance here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MfL_JkcEFbE) was simply to use `compton` as whe window compositing engine.

Don't mess with the X11 config. If you're using the `modesetting` drivers, you're good to go.

Just disable XFCE's compositor, if it's activated, and on a terminal run:

```
compton --backend=glx
```

If that solves the issue, make `compton` start at with every XFCE session. I followed the instructions on [this page](https://duncanlock.net/blog/2013/06/07/how-to-switch-to-compton-for-beautiful-tear-free-compositing-in-xfce/), but I didn't use their config file, just the glx backend setting.

Comment: Just FYI there is updated compositor based on compton called [picom](https://github.com/yshui/picom).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. For now I'll stick to compton: it fixes the problem and is already installed on my system, but I'll take a mental note.